how to compare each row with a reference row and assign a letter column based on the rules?
I have a dataframe (df).  I want to assign groups by comparing each row to the first row (as reference). The rules are:

if all values exact match the first row or at least one value matches but others are "--", that would give "A" in the "result" column;

if all values are "HH" or at least one "HH" with "--" in the row, "B" would be given in the result column;

if any one of values from the first row are mixed with "HH", "C" would be given in the result column;

if all values in a row are "--", "D" would be given in the result column.
 df = read.table(text="ID    M1  M2  M3  M4
 reference   AA  CC  AA  TT
 S1  AA  CC  AA  TT
 S2  HH  HH  HH  HH
 S3  --  CC  AA  TT
 S4  HH  CC  AA  TT
 S5  AA  HH  HH  HH
 S6  HH  --  HH  HH
 S7  AA  CC  AA  HH
 S8  AA  HH  AA  TT
 S9  HH  HH  HH  --
 S10 HH  CC  AA  HH
 S11 HH  --  HH  --
 S12 HH  --  --  --
 S13 --  --  --  --
 S14 --  CC  --  --", header=T, stringsAsFactors=F)



the expected result as:
    ID  M1  M2  M3  M4  result
    reference   AA  CC  AA  TT  A
    S1  AA  CC  AA  TT  A
    S2  HH  HH  HH  HH  B
    S3  --  CC  AA  TT  A
    S4  HH  CC  AA  TT  C
    S5  AA  HH  HH  HH  C
    S6  HH  --  HH  HH  B
    S7  AA  CC  AA  HH  C
    S8  AA  HH  AA  TT  C
    S9  HH  HH  HH  --  B
    S10 HH  CC  AA  HH  C
    S11 HH  --  HH  --  B
    S12 HH  --  --  --  B
    S13 --  --  --  --  D
    S14 --  CC  --  --  A

I thought using R <- unique(unlist(df[1,])) for the first row, S <- unique(unlist(df[-1,])) from other rows, then  X <- sum(S %in% R) to count overlaps (X). count HH represented by "H". if X >0 & H==0 assign "A", if X >0 & H >0 assign "B", if X==0 & H >0 assign "C", if X==0 & H==0 assign "D". I want to have a solution without looping.
your helps are very appreciated.

Motivate others by demonstrating what you have tried to solve your problem.

Have you checked into dplyr::case_when() or data.table::fcase? They let you specify a specific output for each condition.

Since this seems only the beginning of your troubles with this dataset and the data is probably more exensive than the example, I would recommend using additional columns to check for each case. You can then use these columns to come to a conclusion on your result:
df$same = F
df$hh = F
df$empty = F
df$valid = F

for(v in names(df)[2:5]){
  df$same = df$same | df[[v]]==df[1,v]
  df$hh = df$hh | df[[v]]=="HH"
  df$empty = df$empty | df[[v]]=="--"
  df$valid = df$valid | !df[[v]] %in% c("HH","--")
}

df$result = NA
df$result[df$same]="A"
df$result[df$same & df$hh]="C"
df$result[df$hh & !df$valid]="B"
df$result[!df$valid & !df$hh]="D"

There are four new boolean columns that just check for the presence of a specific case (same: at least one value is the same as the first line, hh: At least one value is HH, empty: At least one value is --, valid: At least one value is not HH or --)
Using these columns, the rules then directly apply your conditions for A, B, C, and D.
The result in this case would be:
> df
          ID M1 M2 M3 M4  same    hh empty valid result
1  reference AA CC AA TT  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE      A
2         S1 AA CC AA TT  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE      A
3         S2 HH HH HH HH FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE      B
4         S3 -- CC AA TT  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE      A
5         S4 HH CC AA TT  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE      C
6         S5 AA HH HH HH  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE      C
7         S6 HH -- HH HH FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE      B
8         S7 AA CC AA HH  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE      C
9         S8 AA HH AA TT  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE      C
10        S9 HH HH HH -- FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE      B
11       S10 HH CC AA HH  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE      C
12       S11 HH -- HH -- FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE      B
13       S12 HH -- -- -- FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE      B
14       S13 -- -- -- -- FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE      D
15       S14 -- CC -- --  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE      A

The advantage of this solution is that it is easily scalable to more special cases and checks and allows retracting of causes for a specific result.

There are plenty of options. A few:

base nested ifelse()
base apply() + if ... else if ...
dplyr::case_when()
{data.table} + apply() + and/or fcase()/fifelse()

Many resources can be found on SO, search for such terms.
Here is one in base with apply() + if...else if... to get you started:
df$result = apply(df[-1L], 1L, \(i) { 
  st = sum(i == df[1L,-1L]); nHH = any(i == "HH"); ns = sum(i == "--")
  if(st==4L | st >= 1L & ns==(4L-st)) "A" else 
    if(nHH & sum(i %in% c("HH", "--"))==4L) "B" else 
      if(st & nHH) "C" else if(ns==4L) "D" })

> df
          ID M1 M2 M3 M4 result
1  reference AA CC AA TT      A
2         S1 AA CC AA TT      A
3         S2 HH HH HH HH      B
4         S3 -- CC AA TT      A
5         S4 HH CC AA TT      C
6         S5 AA HH HH HH      C
7         S6 HH -- HH HH      B
8         S7 AA CC AA HH      C
9         S8 AA HH AA TT      C
10        S9 HH HH HH --      B
11       S10 HH CC AA HH      C
12       S11 HH -- HH --      B
13       S12 HH -- -- --      B
14       S13 -- -- -- --      D
15       S14 -- CC -- --      A

Also, investigate coercion to Boolean, replacing "--" with NA, and, potentially, rowsum().
